# Visualizer Returns all zeros when using queued MediaPlayer

Tags: android

I created a `MediaPlayer` then queued the next `MediaPlayer` using `setNextMediaPlayer`.
I then created a `Visualizer` based on the first player. All works well until the song changes over and then the visualizer just sends -128's or zeros.

I tried using `OnInfoListener` to catch the `MEDIA_INFO_STARTED_AS_NEXT` event and use the passed in `MediaPlayer` to recreate the visualization. I verified this player is playing, but it still doesn't receive any valid data.

This is how I create the `Visualizer`.  NOTE I `release`() the old `Visualizer` right before calling this.:

```
public Visualizer createVisualizer(MediaPlayer _player) {
    if (_player != null) {
        Visualizer visualizer = new Visualizer(_player.getAudioSessionId());
        visualizer.setScalingMode(Visualizer.SCALING_MODE_NORMALIZED);
        visualizer.setCaptureSize(Visualizer.getCaptureSizeRange()[0]);
        visualizer.setDataCaptureListener(this, Visualizer.getMaxCaptureRate() / 4, true, false);
        visualizer.setEnabled(true);
        return visualizer;
    }
    return null;
}
```

The only thing I can think of is it has something to do with reusing the listener, but I really have no idea at this point.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working by forcing the audioSessionId of the next player to be the same as the first player by using:

```
playerNext.setAudioSessionId(playerFirst.getAudioSessionId());
```